# Normalizing traits/statistics.

Tags: probability, statistics

**Question will be updated later.**

Normalization is prolly related to trait_types:

```
Trait_type = background
Trait = green
Trait = Blue
```

Will update this later today.

My goal is to create an app that calculates rarity scores of traits.
The rarity score is a formula like so:

`Rarity score = 1/(%Chance Of occurrence)`

Let's say I have a trait that has 10% chance of occurring.

The rarity score for this trait will be:

10 = 1/(10%).

This score will be without trait normalization.

The first score is calculated via the formula above.

What I am trying to find out is how the process of trait normalization (or rarity normalization) is done with the second example.

All I know is the % chance of getting the trait and the final score.
What is a possible calculation/normalization that is done with the second example?

If any more info is needed ill provide it.
Ty for the help and I hope this will get solved!

`Score with no trait normalization`

| ID | Trait 1 | Trait 2 | Trait 3 | Trait 4 | Trait 5 | Trait 6 | Trait 7 | Trait 8 | Trait 9 | Trait 10 | Trait 11 | Trait 12 | Trait 13 | Trait 14 | Trait 15 | Trait 16 | Trait 17 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 243.88 | 70.91 | 12.84 | 8.10 | 7.72 | 7.00 | 6.78 | 6.32 | 5.13 | 4.50 | 4.43 | 3.91 | 3.45 | 3.37 | 2.29 | 1.39 | 1.36 |

Total score: 393.36

`Score With Trait normalization`

| ID | Trait 1 | Trait 2 | Trait 3 | Trait 4 | Trait 5 | Trait 6 | Trait 7 | Trait 8 | Trait 9 | Trait 10 | Trait 11 | Trait 12 | Trait 13 | Trait 14 | Trait 15 | Trait 16 | Trait 17 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 35.87 | 10.98 | 10.14 | 6.19 | 5.67 | 5.30 | 5.29 | 4.96 | 3.78 | 3.74 | 3.72 | 3.63 | 3.37 | 3.35 | 1.77 | 0.61 | 0.55 |

Total score: 108

Reference links:

[Wikipedia about normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalization)

[Explanation about current used formula](https://raritytools.medium.com/ranking-rarity-understanding-rarity-calculation-methods-86ceaeb9b98c)

Comment: There is no obvious relationship between unnormalized and normalized scores, except perhaps monotonicity.  In particular compare what happens to Traits 2 and 3.  Perhaps it is affected by other traits we cannot see

Comment: I think i messed up the question.

Each trait as a trait_type.

I am guessing the normalization is related to traits of the same type and not traits of the same ID.

Example:

Trait_type: background
Trait: Blue
Trait: Green

Etc... i will update question later to include that.

Comment: @Henry Is there a possibility to send a private dm/chat to explain the problem farther and show examples of the new graph?

Comment: I am afraid I do not use SE chat

Comment: @Henry Updated question to be more accurate and with more data and information here:
[question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4263674/normalizing-traits-statistics-based-on-trait-count-for-each-trait-type)